# Are there items bigger than an aircraft section transported by air today?

Tags: cargo

This [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/how-are-off-wing-jet-engines-transported) about engine transportation made me wonder what is the size of the biggest item ever transported. Then I remembered that it should have been a space shuttle (either [Buran](http://www.airliners.net/photo/VKK-Buran/2396061/&sid=c909ba0928fded5d0a3bdb818413216c) or the [American Space Shuttle](http://www.airliners.net/photo/NASA/Rockwell-Space-Shuttle/0293415/&sid=8f41d23fa040e87d85219e7d72d23821)), but those items are no longer transported. Nowadays whole aircraft sections are transported, thanks to [A300-600ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_Beluga) and [B747LCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Dreamlifter).

Are there cargo items bigger than a high by-pass ratio jet engine or an aircraft section that are transported by air today (in 2015)? How are those item handled?

Comment: Today no, in the recent past it was the space shuttle. An entire aircraft

Comment: Is [SpaceShipTwo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceShipTwo) considered "cargo" akin to the shuttle?

Comment: does the size of the cargo count? A small aircraft can be larger than a large aircraft section... Or an M-1 battle tank, or a patrol boat, both of which have been transported by C-17s.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you are not restricted by the size of a cargo hold, your cargo can become much bigger. See below how a [Mil-26](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-26) lifts the fuselage and wing root of a Tu-134. I have not checked whether this is a record, but I would expect that the world record will involve the Mil-26 somehow.

[image: Mil-26 lifting a Tu-134 carcass, seen from below]

<sub>Mil-26 lifting a Tu-134 carcass, seen from below ([source](http://www.businessinsider.com/russia-mi-26-helicopter-llft-biggest-2014-5?IR=T))</sub>

Comment: I almost forgot an helicopter can carry cargo thanks to sling!

Comment: Hmmm... So, I guess it depends on how you define 'aircraft section' as to whether this counts as "bigger than an aircraft section" or whether it counts as _being_ an aircraft section. :) It's at least bigger than a _fuselage_ section.

Comment: @reirab Chinooks and Super Stallions (and others) lifted entire jet fighters, including F-4 Phantoms, not small aircraft by any means, in Vietnam. They could do it today, and maybe do on occasion (maybe in Afghanistan).

Comment: @jwenting: … but if you need to airlift an MH-47E from 8500 ft, the [Mi-26 is your only bet!](http://www.airspacemag.com/flight-today/we-haul-it-all-10713658/?all)

Answer (score 21):

According to Wikipedia, the [An-225](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya) is the world's largest cargo aircraft and it's transported both the heaviest and longest items of cargo ever carried by air:

> On 11 August 2009, the heaviest single cargo item ever sent via air
>   freight was loaded onto the Antonov 225. At 16.23 metres (53.2 ft)
>   long and 4.27 metres (14.0 ft) wide, its consignment, a generator for
>   a gas power plant in Armenia along with its loading frame, weighed in
>   at a record 189 tonnes (417,000 lb)
>
> [...]
>
> On 11 June 2010, the An-225 carried the world's longest piece of air
>   cargo, when it flew two new 42-meter test wind turbine blades from
>   Tianjin, China

It's also carried the [Buran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_%28spacecraft%29) spacecraft (the 'Soviet space shuttle'), which was actually what the aircraft was originally built for.

The An-225 is [still in operation](http://www.antonov.com/aircraft/transport-aircraft/an-225-mriya) and the operator gives some examples of large cargo that can be carried:

> The aircraft has the spacious cargo compartment with length of 43.32
>   m, width of 6.4 m and height of 4.4 m, that allows carrying a variety
>   of cargoes inside. For instance,
>
> - sixteen standard aeronautical containers of UAC−10 type;
> - 50 cars;
> - single piece of cargoes up to 200 t (turbines, generators, dump trucks − Belaz, Kamatsu, Euclid, etc.).

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this counts since it's still in development and production, but Scaled Composites' [Stratolaunch Carrier Aircraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_Stratolaunch) (dubbed the *Roc*) will almost certainly shatter any existing records for payload capacity. Its mating system is designed to hold up to 500,000 lb (230,000 kg.) Its intended payload, like that of [WhiteKnight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_White_Knight) and [WhiteKnight 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_Composites_White_Knight_Two), is a rocket stack mounted between the twin fuselages to be air launched. At least as of December 2011, the first flight test [was indeed scheduled for 2015](http://www.space.com/13915-paul-allen-giant-plane-stratolaunch-systems-private-space.html), so I guess it technically does meet the 'in 2015' criterion for this question. :)

The specific 'item to be carried' in this case is the [Pegasus II rocket stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_II_(rocket)) with a gross weight of 465,000 lb. (211,000 kg,) [according to Aviation Week](http://aviationweek.com/blog/stratolaunch-quietly-making-progress).

Stratolaunch carrier aircraft carrying a Pegasus II:

[image: Stratolaunch Carrier mated to Pegasus II]
Source: [BusinessInsider](http://static.businessinsider.com/image/51fc173c6bb3f7ff5c00000a/image.jpg)

The carrier aircraft will also have the largest wingspan of any aircraft to date:

[image: Stratolaunch Carrier Aircraft wingspan comparison]
Source: [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stratolaunch_comparison.svg#/media/File:Stratolaunch_comparison.svg)

Comment: On first glance I thought that 3D model was made up in Kerbal Space Program :)

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen what do you think SC uses in lue of Autocad ;)