# What is the heaviest payload ever carried by a single main rotor helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, rotorcraft

What is the most heavy payload ever carried by a single main rotor Helicopter?

Comment: Largest by volume or weight?

Comment: The [MIL MI-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-26) can carry more than 20 tons, including the recovery of the Chinook in Afghanistan. It is the most powerful production helicopter in the world, and holds the record for lifting to 2000 meters of 123,153lbs (including the aircraft). The Chinook on the other hand is only rated to about 10 tons (20,100lbs or so).

Comment: Some load is very flexible, e.g. water for fire fighting, concrete for Chernobyl, so it's safe to assume the largest helicopter has been used to it's full capacity, if not overloaded occasionally.

Comment: [Related answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/14339/62)